# Evaluate $\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}$$

I tried

$$\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}=-\int\frac{e^{2x}}{2}\frac{(2x+1)^2 - 4x(2x+1)}{(2x+1)^4} dx+\frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}$$

I also tried

$$\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}=-\int\frac{-1}{4x+2}(2xe^x + e^{2x}) dx + \frac{2xe^x + e^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}=\int\frac{xe^x}{2x+1}dx+\int\frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}dx+\frac{2xe^x + e^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}$$

They don't seem promising.

Comment: In your second try, the integral terms on the RHS sum up to $$\int\frac{xe^x}{2x+1}dx+\int\frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}dx=\int\frac{(2x+1)e^x}{4x+2}dx,$$ which looks quite "promising" to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=xe^{2x}, \;du=(2x+1)dx$ and $\displaystyle dv=\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}dx,\; v=-\frac{1}{2(2x+1)}$ to get

$\displaystyle\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}\,dx= -\frac{xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)}-\int-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}dx=-\frac{xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)}+\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+C=\color{blue}{\frac{e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+C}$

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Let $2x+1=v\iff2x=v-1$

$$\int\dfrac{e^{2x}x}{(2x+1)^2}dx=\dfrac1{2e}\int\dfrac{e^v(v-1)}{v^2}dv$$

$$\int\dfrac{e^v(v-1)}{v^2}dv=\int\left(e^v\dfrac{d(1/v)}{dv}+\dfrac{d(e^v)}{dv}\dfrac1v\right)dv=\int d\left(\dfrac{e^v}v\right)=?$$

Comment: More generally $$\int e^x[f(x)+f'(x)]dx=e^xf(x)+K$$

Answer (score 1):

An integration by parts way:

$$\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}$$

Let $u = e^{2x}, dv = \frac{x}{(2x+1)^2}dx$, then $du = 2e^{2x}dx,v = \frac{1}{8x+4}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1)$

$$=(\frac{1}{8x+4}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1))\times e^{2x} - \int (\frac{1}{8x+4}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1))\times 2e^{2x}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{8x+4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1)e^{2x} - \int \frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}-\frac{1}{2}\int \log(2x+1)\times e^{2x}dx \tag{1}$$

For the part of $\frac{1}{2}\int \log(2x+1)\times e^{2x}dx$:

By integration by parts:

Let $u = \log(2x+1), dv = e^{2x} dx$,$du = \frac{2}{2x+1} dx,v =\frac{e^{2x}}{2}$
$$\int \log(2x+1)\times e^{2x}dx = \\ \frac{e^{2x}\log(2x+1)}{2}-\int\frac{2}{2x+1} \frac{e^{2x}}{2} =\\
\frac{e^{2x}\log(2x+1)}{2}-\int\frac{e^{2x}}{2x+1}  $$

Substitute into $(1)$.

$$\frac{1}{8x+4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1)e^{2x} - \int \frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{e^{2x}\log(2x+1)}{2}-\int\frac{e^{2x}}{2x+1}) =\\\frac{1}{8x+4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1)e^{2x} - \int \frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}-(\frac{e^{2x}\log(2x+1)}{4}-\int\frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2})=\\ \frac{1}{8x+4}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{4} \log(2x+1)e^{2x} - \int \frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}-\frac{e^{2x}\log(2x+1)}{4}+\int\frac{e^{2x}}{4x+2}=\frac{e^{2x}}{8x+4}$$